# django No module named

Tags: django, импорт

Не могу ничего импортировать в django.
Любые библиотеки установленные через pip или иначе.
любой импорт с ошибкой No module named...
куда копать?

Comment: виртуальное окружение создавали?

Comment: нет django установлен без виртульного окружения

Comment: самое интересное что если запускать внутрениий сервер 127.0.0.1:8000 все импортируется нормально, а если через nginx+uwsgi то ошибки импорта

Comment: @user1654251 если внутренний работает, проблема в настройке внешнего. в конфигах uwsgi и nginx прописаны пути к проекту? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/deployment/wsgi/uwsgi/